# ionic push notifications on ios not delivered

Tags: ios, push-notification, ionic-framework

I'm trying to implement ionic push notifications as it says in ionic tutorial. In development mode I received notification, that was shown as alert. But building app with production SSL cert and distribution provision profile only sends notification, but not delivers to iPhone (message status is 'success'). The app is installing via Testflight. Does anybody faced the same problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Did you ever manage to get push notifications working in test flight? What about production? Mine are working fine in development but now not in test flight.

Comment: @Nick , I forgot to report, all is fine now, I build app with default XCode provision profile (XC*) and it works in testflight and production. The one issue left: the first ios notification takes a lot of time to be delivered (or even dissapeared)